# Why does Retroarch can't start on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: xorg, games, amdgpu

My system is Ubuntu 21.04 rendered by x11.

Snap version of Retroarch usually runs fine, but recently, every time I try to launch it, it won't start.

I tried with a terminal, and here is the output.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
amdgpu_device_initialize: amdgpu_query_info(ACCEL_WORKING) failed (-13)
amdgpu: amdgpu_device_initialize failed.
```

I think that the problem could come from the GPU, or from a lack of permissions.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance - Nerincet

Comment: Are you trying to run the program as root?

Comment: No, I run retroarch as common user.